# generic cross join on table based on user choice of column

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

I need to perform a cross join on a table columns in my database. I use linq and C# to do this. Here is the code i wrote:

```
var res = (from item_1 in set1
           join item_2 in set_2 on new
           {
               item_1.columnA,
               item_1.columnB,
               item_1.columnC,
               item_1.columnD,
               item_1.columnE,
               //etc...
           }
           equals new
           {
               item_2.columnA,
               item_2.columnB,
               item_2.columnC,
               item_2.columnD,
               item_2.columnE,
               //etc...
           }
           select new { item_1,item_2};
```

I have an asp.net page where users can choose which columns they would like the cross joins to be performed on. And the query should reflect their choice. Some users would only want 2 of of the columns to be used while other will select 10.

I obviously do not want to repeat this query in some switch statement and include the selected columns. I'm wandering if there is a generic way of doing this. Passing a lambda expression ... I'm just not sure how this should be done.
Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Btw, this is not called a cross join. A cross join is an unfiltered cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blogpost from Scott Gu about [**Dynamic LinQ**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

It not only contains an explanation on the matter, links to downloads and examples are also provided. Hope this helps!

Comment: What is suggested by this library is not exactly what i'm looking for. It  would require some complex string concatenation which i'm trying to avoid. I was more looking for something that include lambad exåpression and generics.